# Request.args does not have all form data

Tags: python, forms, flask

I am trying to submit a form to my Flask application. It has 3 named groups:

- csrf token
- An issue action, which is one of two buttons
- An issue type, which is one of three buttons

Here is my form code:

```
<form method="get" action="{{url_for('connectivity.homeBase')}}">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<div class="column" style="width:48%; margin-left:1%; margin-right:1%;">
    <div class="columnContainer" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="buttonWrapper" style="width:100%; margin:5px;">
            <button class="submitButton issueAction" id="newIssue" name="issueAction" value="newIssue" type="button" style="width:145px; height:75px; text-align:center;">New</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column" style="width:48%; margin-left:1%; margin-right:1%;">
    <div class="columnContainer" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="buttonWrapper" style="width:100%; margin:5px;">
            <button class="submitButton issueAction" id="updateIssue" name="issueAction" value="updateIssue" type="button" style="width:145px; height:75px; text-align:center;">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; height:25px; display:block; clear:both;">
</div>
<h3>Is this a partner outage, partner maintenance, or company outage?</h3>
<hr>
<div class="column" style="width:31%; margin-left:1%; margin-right:1%;">
    <div class="columnContainer" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="buttonWrapper" style="width:100%; margin:5px;">
            <button class="submitButton issueType" id="partnerOutage" name="issueType" value="partnerOutage" type="button" style="width:145px;; height:75px; text-align:center;">Partner Outage</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column" style="width:31%; margin-left:1%; margin-right:1%;">
    <div class="columnContainer" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="buttonWrapper" style="width:100%; margin:5px;">
            <button class="submitButton issueType" id="partnerMaintenance" name="issueType" value="partnerMaintenance" type="button" style="width:145px; height:75px; text-align:center;">Partner Maintenance</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column" style="width:31%; margin-left:1%; margin-right:1%;">
    <div class="columnContainer" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="buttonWrapper" style="width:100%; margin:5px;">
            <button class="submitButton issueType" id="companyOutage" name="issueType" value="companyOutage" type="button" style="width:145px; height:75px; text-align:center;">company Outage</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; height:25px; display:block; clear:both;">
</div>
<h3 id="submitLabel">You must select an action and issue type to proceed.</h3>
<hr>
<div class="buttonWrapper" style="width:100%; margin:5px;" type="submit">
    <button class="submitButton" style="width:145px; height:75px; text-align:center;">GO!</button>
</div>
```

In Python, I'm simply trying to print the request.args:

```
@bp.route('/homeBase', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def homeBase():
    print(request.args)
    return render_template('connectivity/homeBase.html')
```

The only item from the form that gets printed is the CSRF token. I have properly named my groups of buttons, given each a unique value attribute, and wrapped them all in a form tag.

Why does Flask only receive the CSRF token from the client? By my understanding I should be able to see an issueAction and an issueType in the request but it is not there.

I could probably code this using a WTForm and fix the issue but I want to understand why this approach is flawed before I abandon it.

Comment: I do indeed have a closing form tag, my copy-paste must have missed it and I can't find a place to edit my question.

Comment: where the inputs that you are trying to send because all I can see is a bunch of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to use `<button>` as though it were a [radio button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) or possibly checkboxes, which I don't think will work normally.  For example, when a user clicks on one of those buttons, how does it visually indicate which action they've selected?  That's what radio buttons and checkboxes are for.  When you click a plain button it just....gets clicked.  But then nothing happens unless it it has `type="submit"` (the default) or has some JavaScript event handler attached to it.  I don't think button "values" are submitted in forms unless it's the submit button itself.

If you insist you could probably make it work with some JavaScript, but probably better to use the appropriate form element type.

Comment: I am using JS to change the styling once it has been clicked. I suppose I can switch to radio buttons but I don't see why a button in a form would not post correctly. I'll change my approach, thanks.

Comment: That's just not how buttons work in HTML forms.  With the exception of the submit button (of which you could have more than one, and thus take a different action server-side depending on which one it was clicked) there is no way for a user to provide a "value" to a form input by clicking a button.  Any styling you do after the fact with JavaScript is outside the bounds of HTML.  You can also style radio buttons in many ways. E.g. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: But also if you are already using JS to handle button clicks you can use that to update the form's value.

Comment: That's right, I could probably use hidden fields to sync things up and send to the server. 

The reason I went against traditional radio buttons is I was having trouble making a radio button look like a normal button. I want a big rectangle with the label inside, not a circle radio button with the label next to it.

Comment: I ended up using hidden input fields to keep everything in the form tag synced up and sent to the server correctly. This allows me to use simple button styling instead of complicated radio button styling to achieve the same feel, and I only needed a couple jquery event handlers to make it work.